# How to delete empty lines in a file using Emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs, str-replace

In Emacs, how to remove all empty lines (including tabs and spaces) in file?

Can `M-x replace-regexp` do the trick?

I can find the empty lines with regexp: **^[st]*$**, but don't know how to replace it by deleting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` and `$` just match starts and ends of lines, not the actual end-of-line characters. You have the explicitly type the newline in the expression to replace it.

To achieve your goal, replace-regexp

```
^[[:space:]]*^J
```

with nothing (empty text). To enter `^J`, first press Control and Q, then Control and J. In the entry field, this shows up as an actual line change.

Comment: Thanks for the tips of ^J, I used M-x replace-regexp ^C-q C-j <Enter> <Enter> solved the problem.

Comment: Your method removed all lines returns, I just want to remove the empty lines.

Comment: True, forgot the `^` in the beginning (edited now). To match your original spec "including tabs and spaces" you do need the `[[:space:]]*` part, though.

Answer (score 13):

`M-x flush-lines RET ^[[:space:]]*$ RET` is probably the canonical way to do that.

Comment: This is more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: To me `M-x flush-lines RET ^$ RET` alone is able to delete empty lines

Comment: @Prasanna: It depends if you consider lines that contain just a few spaces to be "empty".